# How does the 401k work if i move from US to canada working for same company?

Tags: united-states, canada, 401k

I have been working in USA from past 15 years and now planning to move to Canada for the same company. So is there a 401k equivalent in Canada where i can continue contributing ? Or i can still contribute to US 401k while working in Canada ? Any suggestions ?

Comment: You're a Canadian or an American citizen?  Are you planning to stay in Canada indefinitely, or is this just temporary for this job?  How long, if temporary, is it likely to be?

Comment: I am neither a Canadian or American. I belong to china. and yes this move is more than likely for 5 years.

Comment: Did you ask HR?  To me that would be the first step.

Comment: Eventually i will but right now its too early to ask HR at this point of time ,so i am posting here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Canadian retirement account is called an RRSP.  Investopedia has a good [introductory article](https://www.investopedia.com/university/rrsp/) on what an RRSP is.  It's not exactly the same as a 401(k) or an IRA, but has some of the same elements of both, including (sometimes) employer matching contributions and tax benefits.  You don't have to be a Canadian citizen, but you do have to be filing a Canadian tax return, among other requirements.

Whether this will be a good idea for you or not will depend on where you go afterward.  The US and Canada, for example, have a treaty that governs how RRSP income is taxed; many other countries do as well, but not all.  You may want to research whatever country you expect to move to next, and/or your country of citzenship (in your case, China), to see how they would tax an RRSP.

Comment: This really helped for now.